# Seam 2.3 XSD error in page.xml

Tags: xml, jboss, xsd, seam3

I am upgrading an application from seam 2.2 to 2.3. I switched my login page .xml to uses *-2.3.xsd. I took the changes from the pages.xml in the migration guide. My error is

> s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema
>   elements ...

My XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns="http://jboss.com/products/seam/pages"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.com/products/seam/pages         
  http://jboss.com/products/seam/pages-2.3.xsd">
</page>
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the JBoss XSDs have moved and didn't leave forwarding information.

I found them here now: [**JBoss XSDs**](http://www.jboss.org/schema/)

So, your page.xml file can be fixed up to use the new location (and namespace):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/pages"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/pages
                          http://jboss.org/schema/seam/pages-2.3.xsd">
</page>
```

After making these changes, page.xml will validate successfully.

Comment: Isn't the starting tag pages?

Comment: @Nitb: What do you mean?

Comment: The root element should be pages and not page. Isn't it?